# Applying Fill for Adjacent Cells in the Same Row, Based on Value in the First Cell (XlsxWriter)

Tags: python, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to find a way to set a background fill for adjacent cells based on the value on the first cell.

For example, if the first cell contains the value 'Apples' or 'Pears', on top of highlighting the first cell, I'd like to highlight the other cells up to the column length like so:
[Highlighting Other Cells Based on First Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdN5k.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdN5k.png)

I've tried using the following code but it returns an invalid syntax error:

```
   for row in len(df):
           worksheet.conditional_format(row+1, 1, {'type':'cell', 'criteria':'==','value':'"Apples"', 'format': highlight, 'multi_range': row+1, 1 row_1, 1, row+1, 5})
```

Please help!

Thanks!!